# How to Pass variables from one Jenkins job to another Jenkins job and use it in maven build commands

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-cli

I have to setup selenium UI automation job for my project. First job will run all test cases and failed cases will be saved in a static file location.

I need to trigger a downstream job, where I need to use the file value as input parameter.

I have written code to read content from file (Execute Windows Batch Command)

```
set /p failedCases=<failedCases.txt
```

How can I pass this to downstream job? I need to use this in downstream project as maven build parameter, like below.

```
mvn clean install -Dgroups=${failedCases}
```

I thought, setting environment variable in first job and read it from second job should do the work, but, as am new to Jenkins, I am not sure, how to do this. Any help or suggestion is much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the value of the failedCases variable from one Jenkins job to another, you can use the "Parameterized Trigger" plugin. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to achieve this:

1. Install the "Parameterized Trigger" plugin in your Jenkins instance if you haven't already. You can install it from the Jenkins plugin manager.
2. In your first job, after reading the content from the file, set the failedCases value as an environment variable using the "EnvInject Plugin". You can install this plugin from the Jenkins plugin manager as well.
3. In your existing code, add the following line after reading the content from the file:

   echo "failedCases=${failedCases}" > env.properties

This will create a file named env.properties containing the environment variable failedCases.

4. Add a build step in your first job to archive the env.properties file. This will make the file available for downstream jobs to access. You can use the "Archive the artifacts" post-build action for this.
5. In your first job, add the "Parameterized Trigger" build step. Configure it as follows:

   Select the option "Trigger/call builds on other projects".
   Specify the name of your downstream project in the "Projects to build" field.
   Under the "Predefined Parameters" section, click on the "Add Parameters" button and select "Parameters from properties file".
   In the "Properties File Path" field, enter env.properties. This will read the environment variable from the file archived by the first job.
6. In your second job, modify the Maven build command to use the groups parameter as you mentioned:

   mvn clean install -Dgroups=${failedCases}

Please let me know if this helps.